# How to redirect to another page when user click on json data on screen and pass symbol value to another class

Tags: reactjs, react-native, fetch, expo, screen

I am using react native and expo. I have some json data on the screen (similator iOS) such as

```
A
Acompany
B
Bcompany
```

here A is symbol and Acompany is name

When user click on it it should redirect to another screen such as (Stock.js) and pass the `symbol` as well? How can I redirect it to another screen when user click on it and send this data (`symbol`)?

My code:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import {
  StyleSheet,
  View,
  TouchableWithoutFeedback,
  Keyboard,
  FlatList,
  TextInput,
  Button,
  Text,
} from "react-native";
import { useStocksContext } from "../contexts/StocksContext";
import { scaleSize } from "../constants/Layout";
import { Ionicons } from "@expo/vector-icons";

import { ListItem } from "react-native";

export default function SearchScreen({ navigation }) {
  const { ServerURL, addToWatchlist } = useStocksContext();

  const [state, setState] = useState({
    /*  initial state here */
    myListData: [],
  });
  const [search, setSearch] = useState("");

  useEffect(() => {
    renderWithData();
    // FixMe: fetch symbol names from the servner and save in local SearchScreen state
  }, []);

  const updateSearch = (text) => {
    setSearch(text);
  };

  renderWithData = () => {
    return fetch("http://131.181.190.87:3001/all")
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((json) => {
        setState({
          isLoaded: true,
          myListData: json,
        });
        setTimeout(() => {
          console.log(state.myListData);
        }, 10000);
      });
  };

  let filteredItems = state.myListData.filter((item) => {
    return (
      item.symbol.toUpperCase().indexOf(search.toUpperCase()) !== -1 ||
      item.name.indexOf(search) !== -1
    );
  });

  let movies = filteredItems.map((val) => {
    return (
      <View key={val.symbol} style={styles.text}>
        <Text style={styles.text}>{val.symbol}</Text>
        <Text style={styles.text}>{val.name}</Text>
      </View>
    );
  });

  return (
    <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={Keyboard.dismiss}>
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <TextInput
          style={styles.textinput}
          placeholder="Search here"
          placeholderTextColor="white"
          value={search}
          onChangeText={(text) => updateSearch(text)}
        />

        <Text>csdn</Text>
        <View style={styles.text}>{movies}</View>
      </View>
    </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  textinput: {
    color: "white",
    height: "20",
    fontSize: 18,
  },
  text: {
    color: "white",
    backgroundColor: "black",
  },
  flatstuff: {
    color: "white",
  },

  // use scaleSize(x) to adjust sizes for small/large screens
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use a navigation library to support the navigation of your app
You can refer the react-native-navigation [here](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigating)

Once you have basic stack setup like below

```
    <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={SearchScreen} />
    <Stack.Screen name="Details" component={DetailsScreen} />
```

You can navigate like below

```
navigation.navigate('Details',{text:'123'})
```

You can access the params like below from the details screen

```
const { text } = route.params;
```

Comment: I get this error when I pass the value symbol to another class: `
It says this3.props.onPress is nt a function (In this3.props.onPress(event); 'this3.props.onPress' is an instance of object`

Comment: how do you pass it ?

Comment: Can you see in your chat? I posted the code as well. I posted here as well

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/icy-wave-5o7eo?file=/src/SearchScreen.js

Comment: you should do   onPress={() => navigation.navigate("Stock",{ text: val.symbol })}

Comment: I tried that and it says the value is undefined. I tried to print the value of `text` in console.

Comment: is there a value for  val.symbol ? can you pass a string ?

Comment: Yes, the value of val.symbol is like the symbols such as A, AAL etc. I can pass a string as well so long as it passes the value of symbol. I need to pass the value of symbol which so ever user clicks on

Comment: For example, if user clicks on `A` symbol it should pass symbol `A` so I can use that to fetch the json data of that particular symbol

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215566/discussion-between-guruparan-giritharan-and-ikea).